# Android google map path disappear during zoom

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with drawing on my custom overlay when I zoom Google map to specific level.
I made my itemized overlay provided default marker, and aver wrote a draw method with path connecting overlay items. Next I added overlay items with Geo coordinates. WhenI run my application it works perfect showing all items with default marker and a line connecting those items. Then I zoom in/out and everything still fine but when I zoom very close my line disappears but markers still visible. If I zoom out line appears back to normal.
Dis problem exist only on actual devices, never on simulator.
Any ideas what it could be?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The same happened to me on my Nexus 7. I solved the issue by changing `android:targetSdkVersion="14"` to `android:targetSdkVersion="8"` in AndroidManifest.

Update: You can use google maps api v2 (MapFragments)

Comment: Likely, answer to your question is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513578/android-mapview-overlay-disappearing-when-zooming-in) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713671/android-map-overlay-disappears-on-zoom/12714185#12714185). It seems that with some SDK versions, there is optimization in place which checks whether the most top and most bottom part of your drawn shape is within the screen bounds. If not, then shape is completely ignored while drawing (even if any part of it intersects the screen contents).

Comment: this is not a proper solution. with this you would be decreasing your sdk version to older. use overlay and drawLine (dont use drawPath, because if you use drawPath you'll get this problem again).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that both points (start and end point) of the line being drawn are visible in the screen after you zoom?
I've realized that on my device that when zooming, if the starting and ending coordinates for a rectangle are out of the screen, the rectangle will not be drwan, even if the center should be visible.

Regards.