# Android Map Overlay Disappears on Zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, zooming

I'm having a headache with Android's Google Maps API...  I draw some overlays on the map and it's all fine, it updates regularly and handles gestures well, no problem...  However, when I zoom in to perhaps level 15-16 or beyond, one or more of the larger polygons aren't redrawn.  This only occurs in cases where the centroid of a circle for example lies beyond the bounds of the screen, and only occurs when zooming in.. it does not occur when zooming out, nor does it occur if one pans the map in any direction (translation).

When zooming in very close, I'm guessing the system disregards the overlay/shape, treating it as unimportant?  I want any shape intersecting with the screen's bounds to be drawn.  Am I missing something obvious here, because I can't seem to find any definitive answer on how to treat this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd a similar problem, but I was using only squares, which make it easier to solve.

**Problem details (at lest with squares):**

canvas.drawRect() only draws the rectangle if both top and bottom of rectangle have coordinates within visible screen. As soon as the top or the bottom of the rectangle have a coordinate outside screen, it's not drawn.

**Solution I've used for squares**

I croped the square to make it always fit within the visible screen coordinates, and it was correctly drawn.

If you are using more complex figures, this solution may be more dificult to implement.

good luck.

Comment: So it's an intended behaviour.  I don't really understand why force drawing any intersecting shape isn't at least an option to toggle or something when drawing the map.  Thanks a lot for the clarification in any case.  Alright then, I'm not sure how to go about solving this issue for circles and other more complex shapes.  I could compute the two intersection points of the screen's bounds and the circle then draw an arc, but I'm guessing that'll rule out any sensible fill options.  I'll have to have a think about it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Stephen I´m using the solution above in a overlay that I build with the only propose of debuging my app. So, as soon as I understood what's going on, and what I could do to avoid it, I moved on without looking for a better solution. Probably, there is a more elegant solution that the one I used. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The way I implemented it was using the `mapviewballons` as library [here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) then using the call to
`super(boundCenter(defaultMarker), mapView);`

The boundCenter keeps the centroid on the screen whose overlay is on screen and on zooming it is unaffected.

Comment: @Stephen: any luck with a solution on this?

Comment: i am using the same library , but still my direction disappears can u share ur solution ?

Comment: None yet. I haven't had enough time to look at it.