# Android MapView overlay disappearing when zooming in

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, overlays

I'm working on a simple Android app for plotting routes on a map.  All is going well, but I have an issue when zooming in on my Samsung Galaxy S2.  It works fine on a Galaxy S3, so I'm wondering whether it's related to memory management on the lower specced device.  It also works fine on the emulator.

Here is equivalent code located in the overlays onDraw method, just condensed for posting here:

```
Point current = new Point();
Path path = new Path();
Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

Iterator<GeoPoint> iterator = pointList.iterator();
if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    projection.toPixels(iterator.next(), current);
    path.moveTo((float) current.x, (float) current.y);
} else return path;
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    projection.toPixels(iterator.next(), current);
    path.lineTo((float) current.x, (float) current.y);
}

Paint roadPaint = new Paint();
roadPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
roadPaint.setStrokeWidth(8.0f);
roadPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
roadPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

canvas.drawPath(path, roadPaint);
```

It's not too dissimilar to most of the sample code floating around for doing this.  I'm just wondering if anyone can confirm my suspicions and advise if there is anything I can do in terms of configuration or tweaks that I can do to force drawing at all zoom levels?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that code above was an equivalent (not the real code you are running) and that's clear because you are returning a `Path` object in a `onDraw()` which you couldn't.

The "compressed form" of code you show should work as well as using the `drawLine()`. So the problem should come from something else (may the original code).

Anyway, I'll give you a couple of hints:

- When the top and bottom of object you are drawing to a canvas are both out of screen, the object is ignored and not drawn. Check if this is not whats happening with your path. See my answer in this post [Android Map Overlay Disappears on Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713671/android-map-overlay-disappears-on-zoom/12714185#12714185)
- You don't need to rebuild the path object every time. You are probably already doing it, and that's why you made the short version above. See my answer in this post with some suggestions to improve path drawing: [Overlay behavior when zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051864/overlay-behavior-when-zooming/13055270#13055270)
- If for some reason you really want to use the slower approach of `drawLine()`, you can use the follwing to make the line look better:

  ```
  paint = new Paint();
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
  paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
  paint.setColor(...);
  paint.setAlpha(...);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(...);
  ```

Finally, if the issue remains, update your question with more relevant code and let me know. Maybe I can help further.

Regards.

Comment: Yep, the function is split into a bunch of methods that encapsulate each step. Great to read in an IDE but too verbose to post.  
I do have a version that caches the path and translates it around but I've removed it until I work out why it was disappearing. I suspect it is to do with the top and bottom of the path as you found out with your rectangles.  
setStrokeJoin and setStrokeCap may be a good fallback.  It's funny you mention it being slower, it's way faster than my current path implementation, just uglier.  
Cheers, Nathan

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Once top and bottom of the path are off the screen, the path isn't drawn. This doesn't happen with the lines solution as it's always on the screen.  Now to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why that only happens on my device and not on the emulator or Galaxy S3.

Comment: Are you using exactly the same points to draw the path on all devices? Are all of them using the same SDK? Behaviour may change with different SDK levels... I checked in my device and emulator, and the path is drawn as long has there is a path segment that starts or finalize within visible screen.

Comment: Regarding speed, a correctly designed utilization of `drawPath()` is 20 times faster then using `drawLine()` in a path with 10.000 points (4 ms against 80 ms per draw call).

Comment: No they're not so it may be SDK dependent and when I get a chance I'll compare.  The GS3 is running 4.0.4, GS2 has 4.1.2 and the emulator is running 4.2.

Comment: Interesting to note the speed.  I rarely have *that* many points so maybe that's why I've not noticed the performance issues of drawLine().

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are painting the overlay yourself for a very specific state of the mapview. You should use [OverlayItem](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem) instead.

The OverlayItem is added to the MapView overlays collection, and the MapView handles all the re-drawing depending on it's own state ( zoom, location, etc )

```
@Override
public void draw( Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow )
{
    super.draw( canvas, mapView, shadow );

    int x1 = -1;
    int y1 = -1;
    int x2 = -1;
    int y2 = -1;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle( Paint.Style.STROKE );
    paint.setColor( GeoLocation.ROUTE_COLOR );
    paint.setStrokeWidth( STROKE_WIDTH );

    for ( int i = 0; i < mRouteGeoPoints.size(); i++ )
    {
        Point point = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels( geoPoints.get( i ), point );
        x2 = point.x;
        y2 = point.y;
        if ( i > 0 )
        {
            canvas.drawLine( x1, y1, x2, y2, paint );
        }
        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is OverlayItem not used for singular items located at a point?  All of the documentation I'd read said that paths need to be drawn by a class extending Overlay.

Comment: That's right. So your code is actually executed on the onDraw of a Overlay subclass ?

Comment: That is correct.  As I said, functionally it appears to work fine, the emulator and GS3 work fine. I do have other apps on the same phone that don't have this problem, so I'm just wondering if there is some magic I'm missing :)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Though, i've posted my draw method to the answer so you can use it to compare it with yours. So far i've not received reports of not working routes on zooming or any other event.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've worked your code into my solution and it solves the problem of not being able to see the route at the higher zoom levels.  Unfortunately now as it's not one continuous line and I'm using quite a wide stroke it doesn't radius the bends properly.  I can live with that.

It appears the OS must be doing some sort of optimisation because the Path is one object versus many small lines.